# Linking Opacity to Z coordinates in the compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency

I have a particle system with tons of particles flying towards the camera. They are supposed to be emerging from a dust storm.

Is there some way to have the particles start invisible, and then become opaque as they travel towards the camera?

I am stuck, trying to take a "mist pass", using that as the factor in a mix node, and mixing the rendered image with a 2nd image. This would do exactly what I needed if the 2nd image could just be a transparent image (just emptiness).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The [Camera Data node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/camera_data.html) gives you the distance from the camera. You can then add a math node to adjust that to get the desired amount of transparency.

[image: distance based transparency]

Comment: You may also find [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/76946/935) interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Transparent and a Diffuse Shader and use a Mix Shader to combine the two. Then add a "Particle Info" node and from that connect "Location" to a "Separate XYZ" node. Then connect the Z to the Mix Shader's factor. Then add a  "Multiply" node to control the amount of transparency.

Then set this material to your particles (assuming their render type is "Object").

[image]

Result

[image]